# Statistical optimization Model for which person should be assigned a lead within each state

Tags: r, regression, optimization

I am working on creating an optimization model based on sales on a particular website. The system assigns the leads to different sales people.

I want to generate a model doesn't randomly assign leads to people, but instead assigns leads generated by particular states to the best performing person in that state.

I have data grouped by 50 States with the following predictors - ID, "Leads Generated", "Leads to Lock", and "Contribution Margin". Here is what the data looks like:

```
   ID   Leads LTL   CM
    1   17  0.000   0.00
    2   18  0.167   0.64
    3   10  0.000   0.00
    4   8   0.125   0.00
    5   2   0.000   0.00
    6   14  0.143   0.71
    7   7   0.143   0.35
```

I have data for each ID for all 50 states. I also have to account for the performance on weekdays and weekends as well as the products at which each sales person is good at. So far, I am working only on two products.

With so many constraints, I am confused where to start. I thought that I can group the data by state and fit regression, but that would not give me the desired result.

Please Let me know if more info on the problem is required in case I am not clear enough in explaining my project.

Comment: What is ID ? Are the Leads the past leads for each sales peson ? What are the columns (more info than the names, please) ? Also, from what I understand it is not a prediction problem but an optimization one, no ?

Comment: @Romain  Yes, you are right- the data is 6 months data; I am trying to build an optimization engine. ID is associated with each individual sales person.                                                                                                LTL- It is the total percentage of locks done by each individual over a period of time.                                                                                            CM- Is calculated based on how much the individual contributes on a particular campaign.

Comment: Ok, then let's say you receive a new lead for state s why don't you simply assign it to the ID with the highest LTL in that state s ?

Comment: No, because a person who generated two leads and converted them will have 100% LTV; and we want to avoid such people. That is the only reason I have taken number of leads in consideration.

Comment: OK, you need to explain you problem more precisely before we can help you more